# Perl and MySQL - Return a field from last row of a table using DBI possibly with last_insert_id?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, last-insert-id

I am trying to return a members `firstname` field from the table `users` from the last row of `users`.

```
 my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password) or die "$DBI::errstr";
    my $LastID = $dbh->last_insert_id(`firstname`); ##but I want from table users
    print qq~$LastID~;
```

This error is returned from above:

```
DBI last_insert_id: invalid number of arguments: got handle + 0, expected handle + between 4 and 5
Usage:    $h->last_insert_id($catalog, $schema, $table_name, $field_name [, \%attr ])
```

So, what would be the "best" way (best being best for server, fastest, least memory, load, least amount of overhead.. whatever) to get the field `firstname` from the last row in the table `users`?

Realize my example above is not to be taken seriously as I have no idea how to do this without just doing something like my crude, but functional: 
(p.s.  UserID is NOT assigned by auto increment but, is in numeric order and a new user gets a higher UserID. Just the way this was when I tackled the pre existing problem.)

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $db_user_name, $db_password) or die "$DBI::errstr";
my $dsn = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT `firstname` FROM `users` ORDER BY ABS(UserID) DESC LIMIT ?,?});
$dsn->execute('1','1') or die "$DBI::errstr";
while(@nrow = $dsn->fetchrow_array()) {
$firstname = $nrow[0];
}
```

I assumed since I was using DBI that may provide the best solution but, I am inexperienced obviously and need some advice and guidance to learn the proper way to do this. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Just to check - in your first code block, the text "firstname" is surrounded by backticks (`), which means Perl will try and execute the contents. I don't know exactly what DBI will do with whatever that returns, but it probably isn't what you want. Maybe that's not your problem though.

Comment: Thanks... I removed and got: Bareword "firstname" not allowed while "strict subs". There is also no reference to what table I need info from either. That is why I mentioned not to take that example seriously as I obviously new to this and don't know what I am doing.

Comment: `last_insert_id` is the wrong tool for the job — its purpose is, more or less, to return the primary key of the most recently inserted record, and not to return arbitrary fields associated with that record. You'll need to solve this with SQL, and [Joel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10621769/132382) is essentially correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that UserID is not auto incrementing, so I'm not sure if [last_insert_id](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#last_insert_id) will work in this situation.  It may, but I'm just not sure.  The document states:

> Typically this would be a value assigned by the database server to a
>   column with an auto_increment or serial type.

I would look to solve this by just using a SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    u.firstname
FROM
    users u
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        MAX(UserID) AS UserID
    FROM
        users
    ) t ON u.UserID = t.UserID
```

The code with DBI would then look like this:

```
my $stmt = 'SELECT u.firstname FROM users u JOIN(SELECT MAX(UserID) AS UserID FROM users) t ON u.UserID = t.UserID';
my $first_name = ($dbh->selectrow_array($stmt))[0];
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks for breaking it down like that so I can understand what is going on there.

Comment: I am assuming this method is "better" than just returning the firstname via "ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1,1 " Like I was before? Perhaps a small explanation of why it is better so, I can understand further?

Comment: @Jim_Bo In your example, you're fetching all the rows from the table, sorting them and then only returning the top row.  This wastes some processing time by having to retrieve a large result set and then order it.  Using my example doesn't pull all the rows, so it may be more efficient.  Realistically, I would use a SQL statement and Perl code that makes sense to you; it's better for you to be able to maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

last_insert_id method takes 4 args. Use like this:

```
  my $id = $connection->last_insert_id(undef, 'myschemaname', 'mytablename', 'mycolumnname');
```

See the DBI pod.

Comment: I read that but, won't that return the mysql last id and not the firstname? I am really new to this and I have read all the DBI man pages but, I need a specific example based on my criteria to understand the "mechanics". Perhaps 30 years ago I would have comprehended this a bit quicker but, not as quick as I used to be.

Comment: If you want the firstname field of the row last inserted run last_insert_id as I show above then select the firstname column with id = to the one last_insert_id returned.

Comment: I tried my $firstname = $dbh->last_insert_id(undef, 'databasename', 'users', 'firstname'); Then print qq~ $firstname~; and it returned "0"; I am so sorry, I am not understanding this at all.